# How can I find out what caused a scroll action in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have some content in a scroll viewer which is scrolling to the initial position (0, 0) in some contrived scenarios. If I look at the call stack in the ScrollChanged event, the entire stack is WPF innards.

Is there a mechanism for tracing the source of an event?

Comment: I would search for any calls to scrollIntoView

Comment: @Blam: None of this code does that. No code here is setting scrolling properties manually.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was some code calling `Focus` on one of the controls contained within the scroll viewer, but the control was set such that it was at the 0,0 position and not visible. The focus action automatically tried to bring the thing into view, which caused the bad behavior. I'm still interested in the general case of determining why something scrolled though...